# How a creature can shift out of existence and back?

Tags: evolution

My "ghosts" are creatures that can exist and not exist at the same time. They have the following characteristics:

- "ghosts" are a species of long-living creatures with 4 limbs, 1 head and they are omnivorous;
- can communicate with one another visually but not auditorily (they cannot produce sound);
- are a predatory species;
- are made of blood and flesh like any other animal on Earth;
- can shift out of existence and then come back to existence (this is the **only** difference from animals known to us).

"Ghosts" fluctuate through existence and non-existence. A "ghost" may appear for a slight moment and become physical then disappear into nothing. *"Ghosts" do not become invisible, they literally jump out of existence*.

"Ghosts" can change location while they are out of our plane of existence. The "ghost" can be in front of a person for a split second then vanish and that person feels something warm touching their shoulder, turning their heads to meet a screaming monster.

What do I need to tweak in the existing laws of our universe to accommodate for the existence of a macrostructure of living matter which can fluctuate through existence and non-existence? Or if it is already possible, how would such a being evolve?

The question is:  **How do I make shifting out of existence plausible or even possible?**

Comment: Ok you need to do a much more detailed explanations what a ghost is and what your story needs them to do, before this can be answered. I suggest trying this in the sandbox first

Comment: Hi Thera. I've voted to close this question, but I'd really like to retract my vote. The problem is that ghosts "don't exist" (from a scientific point of view). What this means is that your question can't be answered with any hope of a best answer unless you explain, exactly, what ghosts are in your world. As written, you can't objectively explain which answer is better between "they're made of dark matter" and "they're a result of quantum entanglement." Please fully explain what a ghost is in your world, then we can help. Thanks.

Comment: @John a ghost is : 1) Alive 2) Made of material things 3) Can dissapear from existance and re-apear at will

Comment: @JBH  a ghost is : 1) Alive 2) Made of material things 3) Can dissapear from existance and re-apear at will

Comment: @Thera that tells us nothing about the rules of your world or the physics that define ghosts. We're willing to help you build your creature, but we won't bring it into existence for you. (a) Explain how you will judge a best answer, (b) explain how the ghost can interact with your world, (c) tell us the rules of your world (since ghosts don't exist in ours, something's different between your world and the real world), (d) what limitations, restrictions, and conditions are we working with, and (e) why do ghosts exist at all? We need details, and you've provided too few.

Comment: Rules of my world are the same as the rules of this world you are inhabitating now as suggested by ''What do I need to tweek in our universe laws to accomodate for the existance of a macro structure of living matter which can fluctuate through existance and inexistance''

Comment: @Thera That is incorrect. Your world has ghosts. This world doesn't. What's different about your world that permits ghosts?

Comment: @JBH how ghost interract.... they can touch things...breathe, reproduce but wait they dissapear and apear again. not too complicated? they are living things therefore they do whatever living things do plus something extra. I can't tell what more details do you want to give you?

Comment: @JBH ''Your world has ghosts. This world doesn't. What's different about your world that permits ghosts?'' that's literally the question. That is literally the question.

Comment: @JBH do you want to me to answer my own question?

Comment: I have a sneaking suspicion that you've put the cart before the horse. It happens. Building a world takes time. You're trying to explain using real-world terms how a ghost manifests, but you have not yet created the rules that allow ghosts to exist in your world. Without those rules, we're just throwing ideas at you - and that's off-topic. I believe you need to take the time to develop "why" ghosts are in your world before you ask us to help you answer "how." Can you explain the nature of your afterlife? Is/are there god(s)? Do they need to eat? The Q is simply too vague.

Comment: @Thera: You need to give us an idea of what you're looking for (what you want your ghosts to be made of, what traits they have). I would also remove the stuff about ghosts existing and non-existing, I believe it would make more sense that they are simply changing from a perceptible state to an imperceptible state.

Comment: @JBH THE QUESTION IS ABOUT WHAT RULES DO I NEED TO CHANGE TO MAKE GHOSTS POSSIBLE NOT ABOUT WHAT ARE GHOSTS, I ALREADY SPECIFIED WHAT QUALIFIES AS A GHOST TO ME. TWICE, TWICE!

Comment: @Alendyias I NEED them to shift from existance to inexistance... not just illusions

Comment: @Thera: I don't mean illusions, actually. I mean that your ghosts are most likely a form of matter with two different possible states, one that humans can't touch or see, and one that humans can. The trouble is, we don't have nearly enough information to answer this question. If we don't know exactly what you want your ghosts to be, we can't figure out how they could plausibly come into being.

Comment: @Thera My close vote is because I do not believe you have specified what a ghost is based on the rules and expectations of this Stack. I apologize that you're frustrated - but you're also not paying attention. Stack Exchange has rules and Worldbuilding.SE has rules. Please visit the [help] and read through the pages describing what you can ask, what you can't ask, and how to ask a good question. It will help you understand my concern.

Comment: @JBH instead of ''ghost'' imagine it only says ''thing that dissapears''

Comment: @Thera It doesn't matter if you call it Ralph. (Or, in the case of your edit, Bob.) Thanks for the edit, it's helped a little bit. You have a physical terrestrial creature (e.g., a cougar) that has the ability to wink "out of existence" and you want to know how that can physically happen? Answer: it can't. We don't know how to shift between dimensions, or enter the astral plane, or any other way of achieving your goal. But if we know "why" you want to do it, we might construct a justification for the author's decision that it can.

Comment: @Thera I made some edits. Please feel free to make additional edits/revert back if you are not satisfied with my version. I put ghosts in quotes so people are not confused with notions of after-life and traditional ghosts.

Comment: You need to define 'existence' for this question to be answerable. Will changing molecular structure count as non-existent? Or maybe multiple planes of reality/existence suit your story better and your creatures are capable of shifting between them? Once you determine what existence is, the answer may become more or less obvious.

Answer (score 3):

Ghosts don't actually have the power to shift in and out of existence. How could they? Something which doesn't exist can't have the power to do anything (naturally including the power to come into existence).

Instead their power is to travel through time. Specifically skip forwards in time. From the outside this appears as them suddenly disappearing without the slightest trace, and then later, reappearing. And as time and space are co-relative, this may indeed be in a completely different location.

---

Another solution is that ghosts are in fact 4 dimensional organisms. Again, they don't actually stop existing, instead they simply move in a direction tangent to our three ordinary spacial dimensions. And then, they move back. While the physics of our universe actually having 4 spacial dimensions is a bit difficult (specifically why we haven't noticed yet), the biology is perfectly consistent.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the comments, there is no way that our universe could have something "stop existing" since that would violate the law of [conservation of mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservation_of_mass).

Instead, there is the need to create an alternative place- in our universe- to where these ghosts can travel. For example, maybe they can teleport to a distant planet.

Alternatively, perhaps the ghosts are able to transform into energy. That won't change the total mass of the universe, based on the [mass-energy equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass%E2%80%93energy_equivalence). But practically it will appear as if they stopped existing, since their existence will not be noticeable to anyone but scientists (who happen to be measuring all the energy in the universe and notice an infinitely small increase of energy).

Comment: Unless these ghosts are very small, everyone around them is going to notice them transforming into energy.  Briefly.

Comment: @jdunlop i was picturing something like taking a human, converting him into energy, and scattering that energy over a very larger area- say the entire atmosphere of planet earth for example. If that could be done near-instantaneously, the relative impact on any one specific location would be very minimal. Of course, I'm being vague about the form of energy since I don't know which one could spread out fast enough and be least noticeable. .

Comment: Most energy would spread out at the speed of light.  That's part of the problem.  Converting a human-sized mass (50kg, so a light human) to energy produces 4.5 x 10^18 joules of energy, or a thousand megatons, give or take.  Distributing the energy isn't the problem, it's preventing the distribution of that energy from annihilating everything around it.